# How React JS index.js file contacting index.html for id references?

Tags: reactjs

I recently get started with react.

My **index.html** contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and **index.js** contains

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My doubt is I didn't mention `index.js` in any script tag in `index.html`. But how it is referencing the `root` div element in `index.html`? I was wondering as it is working fine. Please explain me.

I had run these commands to create the app

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app hello-world
cd hello-world
npm start
```

Comment: webpack is a bundler that bundles your JS to a single file (for instance index.js) and injects it to another (for instance index.html). Read more about webpack on their page, because it is pretty powerful and I can't explain everything they do

Comment: Where I can find that bundled file?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the setup of react-create-app, see in the console where it loads the file from. Most probably from webpack's server memory, because it comes with an own dev server or in dist/ directory

Comment: @Mr_Perfect If you want to see the inner workings of webpack in reactapp, run this command to eject explicit settings. `npm run eject`. In this way you will be able to see commands which create-react-app was using to build your application.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

`Create-React-App` has a very interesting setup.

I started digging in the `package.json` npm script `start`

> "start": "react-scripts start"

That takes me to their binary `react-scripts` under `node_modules/.bin`
I'll post the relevant stuff here.

```
switch (script) {
  case 'build':
  case 'eject':
  case 'start':
  case 'test': {
    const result = spawn.sync(
      'node',
      [require.resolve('../scripts/' + script)].concat(args),
      { stdio: 'inherit' }
    );
```

So this tells me that they are looking for script inside `../scripts/` folder.

So I go to the react-scripts npm module(`node_modules/react-scripts`) and open up the `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js` file since I was doing `npm start`.

Now here is where I found the webpack config I was looking for.
They were specifically referring to `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js`. I'll post the relevant stuff here.

```
entry: [
  // Finally, this is your app's code:
  paths.appIndexJs,
],
plugins: [
  // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: true,
    template: paths.appHtml,
  }),
```

So file referred by `paths.appIndexJs` is the entry file in the webpack config.

And they are using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to load the html at the path `paths.appHtml`.

Final piece of the puzzle is linking this back to the files you posted.
Posting relevant stuff from `paths.js`

```
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);
module.exports = {
  ...
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveApp('src/index.js'),
  ...
}
```

So inside your application directory,
appHtml is file `public/index.html`
appIndexJs is file `src/index.js`

Your two files in question.
Wow! That was quite a journey..:P

---

**Update 1** - As of `react-scripts@3.x`

The `react-scripts` binary under `node_modules/.bin` has changed the logic as below. Essentially doing the same thing.

```
if (['build', 'eject', 'start', 'test'].includes(script)) {
  const result = spawn.sync(
    'node',
    nodeArgs
      .concat(require.resolve('../scripts/' + script))
      .concat(args.slice(scriptIndex + 1)),
    { stdio: 'inherit' }
  );
```

The webpack configs for dev & prod has been combined into one.
`const configFactory = require('../config/webpack.config');`

The HTMLWebpackPlugin config looks like this - This is since they have to conditionally add production config on top of this

```
plugins: [
  // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
    Object.assign(
      {},
      {
        inject: true,
        template: paths.appHtml,
      },
```

The paths file code has some updates

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
  ...
};
```

Comment: Nice inside of the node_modules. unfortunately I guess they changed some names as I couldn't find node_modules/react-scripts path neither anywhere the node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js file.

Comment: @Carmine Can you please mention your version of react-scripts, I will update the answer if needed.

Comment: This question popped into my mind, went digging into index.html, then started browsing and here I found it!! Good work :)

Comment: @AftabKhan fantastic answer! I really appreciate your way of showing us how to dig up the relevant info! I am a backend person for much of my life, so as a newbie to JS/react, this is like godsend!  Thx!