# React Entry Point: Index.html vs index.js? Where is the node code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read somewhere on the internet that `index.html` is the entry point for a react app. However, the same article then went on to say that `index.js` is the main entry point (as well as for most node apps). So, which one is it?

When someone loads a react app in the browser, I assume `index.js` is run first, which in return loads `index.html`. But how does that happen typically... As in, how does the flow go from loading the app in the browser to first running `index.js`?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Secondly, after `npx create-react-app app`, the code was run using `npm start`. So, I presume node.js is also involved. However, I can't find any familiar looking node code here. Where is the code that makes the server listen to port 3000, for instance?

Comment: From my understanding, HTML and CSS are parsed in the browser first, and then the JS. After the HTML is fully loaded, your React code (should be compiled to normal JS when running in a browser since browsers don't understand "React" but JS), will try to find a hook, in your case "root" div in your `index.html`. And from that point on, everything is rendered by your JS. For me, the entry point for the App is HTML, but for React, `index.js` is its entry point

Comment: [Aditi Lamkhede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7138480) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66909811) saying "I found this thread helpful: [How Index.js and Index.html are connected in React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738421/how-react-js-index-js-file-contacting-index-html-for-id-references) I hope it helps others looking for same."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In simple words:
`index.html` is where all your UI is rendered by React and `index.js` is where all your JS codes exist. So browser, first get index.html and then renders the file. then JS in `index.js` is responsible for all the logical rendering of UI, which takes element with id `root` to be its base element for rendering all the UIs.

Like in vanilla JS, React searches for element with ID `'root'` and keeps all the UI to be rendered inside that element using the virtual DOM concept. You can view this concept.

After you complete the React development, you have to use a build tool to build React App by `npm build` or `yarn build`, which merges all your codes to single file. So when a client requests your site, the server sends `.html` with the JS files. So, at last, JS files manipulates the single `.html` file.

About the `create-react-app`, `react-scripts` package that comes when you create a react app with `npx create-react-app` handles all the requirements to serve a development serve using node. All the files of packages are inside node_moudles.

This links may be helpful:

- [React Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)
- [Introduction to react rendering](https://medium.com/information-and-technology/an-introduction-to-react-rendering-9c24a96b838b)
- [npm build](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build)
- [Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html#what-is-the-virtual-dom)
- [Develpoment server in React from create-react-app](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/#react-scripts)

Comment: Thank you for such an informative answer. Have a great day.

Comment: You are welcome. If this helps your query, you can mark it as the correct answer. That helps :)

Comment: @Grateful, remember to mark TeachMe response as an Answer, top level, BTW.

Answer (score 7):

> I believe you are using `create-react-app`.
> After `npm install`
> when you check a file named `node_modules/react-scripts/config/paths.js` inside the `node_modules` folder. You see the below code.

```
....
....
appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
....
```

paths.appIndexJs is the entry file in the webpack config.

HtmlWebpackPlugin loads the html at the path paths.appHtml.
So inside your application directory,
appHtml is file `public/index.html` and
appIndexJs is file `src/index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the basic theoretical question that even i got when i had started react development. Following is concept responsible for this flow of react-app.

The flow of react-app is fixed and pre-determined when you use npm start, it refers to "react-scripts start" which is a standard command written in react-scripts in-built package...hence it loads ""index.js"" as entry point of react-app always and searches for index.html which is publicly accessible(bcz it is defined in public folder), thus we dont need to link index.js in  in index.html explicitly.

react app is listen on port 3000 by default which is written in react-scripts in-built package, if you want to change it you can eject the react-app by npm eject and then change the pre-defined commands.