# How index.js file is able to communicate with index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

In React project both index.html and index.js file are inside different folder and there is no link in between these two file. Then how we are able target div whose id is root of HTML file by
using document.getElementById("root") inside index.js file.

please answer this in easy language because i have just start learning this , I am compeletly begineer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How React JS index.js file contacting index.html for id references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738421/how-react-js-index-js-file-contacting-index-html-for-id-references)

Comment: Because it is meant to be built. You can do "npm run build" and check the build/index.html file

Answer (score 0):

React is one of the best JS libraries out there. It simplifies the development process without cluttering the implementation details explicitly. The `index.html` and `index.js` get linked during runtime when you start the script. React uses [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) under the hood where the entry for the webpack is `index.js` and when it is run(after all the conversions) it injects the javascript code in the HTML file which is `index.html`. And you can see this injected code in the `index.html` when you build the bundle inside the build folder.