# misunderstanding as for how index.html knows which script to render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have the following html file in my public folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/juno-icon.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Issue Report</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

what I don't understand is, how does it know to render my index.tsx file (in src) without me stating any script tag?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './popup/components/App';
import './popup/styles/index.css';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { QueryClientProvider, QueryClient } from 'react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
})

root.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>
    <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={true} position='bottom-right' />
  </QueryClientProvider>

);

reportWebVitals();
```

it just seem to render it and it seems like a magic to me o_o

how can it possibly know what file to render?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How React JS index.js file contacting index.html for id references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738421/how-react-js-index-js-file-contacting-index-html-for-id-references)

Comment: Thanks! did not even relate it to the CRA configuration.